# Dynamic Height / Gradient under image in DIV using CSS

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am working as an internship for a company and the owner has asked if it would be possible to fade the random images that appear to the right of the website down to near the bottom of the page (that was bland, will go into detail below).

So far, I have set up a test site and here is a page [example](http://lsotest.wrldevelopment.com/index.php/lso-musicians).
The site uses Joomla CMS (not my choice). If you look at the right there is an image of a musician, each refresh pulls up a different musician/image. What my boss wanted me to do (since apparently I'm low on tasks since revamping their site) is to make a fade gradient that starts at black under the image that uses the rest of the pages height to slowly transition to the background color or transparent (I assume the background color would be easier). So far my thoughts are that this is pretty impossible but I thought I would ask you guys anyways.

My main issue is the height right column of the page to dynamically match with the height of the page height... if that is possible. I know how to make it gradient, but the height issue is bugging me!

The CSS for the whole right column (without gradient, obviously) is:

```
#columnrt {
width:200px;
background-color:#673601;
float:right; }
```

If inspecting the source code on the page, the random image shows up in a class called "random-image" in which I have a strong feeling it's generated by Joomla... example so you can identify the what image are I am talking about:

```
<div class="random-image"><img src="/images/stories/sidebar/lubsym_nov11_017-crop.jpg" width="200" height="306"></div>
```

Any input would be nice, thank you all!

PS: unpaid internship... I don't want you guys to think I'm leaching off y'all!

Comment: I understood what you need, however not sure on the exact location what you need it. Probably me just being tired. Do you think you would be able to make a small diagram in Paint or something?

Comment: @Lodder - here is an example random image mockup of one that is on the right side with the gradient effect that I am looking for, except I'm trying to do it dynamically with each page height and with CSS instead of modifying every image: http://imgur.com/WBm6eWt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, your main problem is making the right column as tall as the page, i.e. extend down as far as the main content.  This can be solved by adding to the CSS:

```
#columnrt {
width:200px;
background-color:#673601;
position:absolute;
top: 0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

That will make the height of the right column extend properly, allowing you to add the gradient.

Comment: With some slight editing this is basically what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use below css and one div and your assignment will be completed

```
td { position: relative; }
.bg-gradient { background: blue; min-height: 100%; width: 200px; position: absolute; z-index:-1; }
```

add this div as first child under  '.columnrt'

```
<div class="bg-gradient"></div>
```

give background gradient you desire to '.bg-gradient' in css

Comment: This did not work because of how Joomla handles custom HTML or some other reason... but someone below solved it. Thanks for answering!